# Remote Injection

Tags: c++, winapi

So, i'm injecting a code in the memory of another process like this:

```
void RemoteInj::ExecuteFunction(DWORD Start, DWORD End, DWORD Entry, RemoteArgs* Args)
{
    unsigned long Id;
    int size = End - Start;
    cout << size << endl;
    void* Func = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, size+10, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    void* ep = (void*)(Entry-Start+(DWORD)(Func));
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, Func, (void*)Start, size, NULL);
    void* Data = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(RemoteArgs)+1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, Data, (void*)Args, sizeof(RemoteArgs), NULL);
    cout << hex << Func << endl;
    cout << "Function: 0x" << hex << Start << endl << "End: 0x" << hex << End << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ep, Data, NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

My problem is: If i use calls in that thread, for example:

```
void F(RemoteArgs* arg)
{
    while (true)
    {
        arg->pSleep(50); //Works
                Sleep(50); //doesnt work
    }
    return;
}
```

No need to explain why it doesn't work, i know, it's another process....My question is: Is there a way to make function like this(Sleep()) work, i could try importing to the process also the IAT with the proper distance, do you have a better idea?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect, the reason this doesn't work right off the bat is that the call to Sleep in your process actually goes to a location in your import address table (IAT) which has a jump to the real Sleep implementation in kernel32.dll. Even though the other process also imports kernel32.dll (all processes do), it obviously does not have an identical IAT.

There are ways, but none that I know of are trivial.

Comment: Could you share your knowlage?